# Perform segue depending on the UITableViewCell row selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have a `UITableView` with a few rows **e.g**. row1 , row2 , row3. I also have 3 UIviewControllers e.g. A , B , C.

When I select row1 in the table view I want to display view controller A.

When I select row2 in the table view I want to display view controller B.

When I select row3 in the table view I want to display view controller C.

I want to do this with an if statement.

I have selected the UITableViewCell and ctrl + dragged it over to the view controllers to create a segue that can be called. However it wont let me create multiple segues between the UITableViewCell and the various viewControllers.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("A", sender: self)
    }

    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("B", sender: self)
    }

    if indexPath.row == 2 {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("B", sender: self)
    }

}
```

**I am using swift 2.**

Comment: public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { } use this delegates method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   //handle your code here
}
```

what mistake you have done is:you have handled in didDeselectRowAtIndexPath

[image]

for multiple segues: refer the image

Answer (score 2):

If you have ctrl-dragged a segue from the prototype cell in InterfaceBuilder, this segue is performed without code when the cell is tapped.

To create multiple segues you need to ctrl-drag from the ViewController (the yellow icon on top) to the various destinations.

Comment: and remember you can do any setup that you need in prepareForSegue